# Factorizing Probability distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to read a paper on factor graphs and coming from a cs background I am a little lost on the following proposition.

Not all distributions can be factored into a product of clique potentials.

The example they cite is the uniform distribution over vectors with an even number of ones. Why can't that be factored as such?

EDIT:
To start, what does the uniform distribution over vectors with an even number of ones even look like?